# Redirect to home page without using deprecated methods

Tags: 8, uri, redirection

I am attempting to add some code to a `hook_entity_view_alter()` function to redirect the user to the homepage under a rare condition with `RedirectResponse`.

I understand the method to accomplish this is along these lines (taken from [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146185/how-to-create-a-redirection-in-drupal-8)):

```
$response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($url);
$response->send(); // don't send the response yourself inside controller and form.
return;
```

My issue is that I am not sure how to format `$url`. Most articles on the topic, such as [this one](http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/88/page-redirection-on-drupal-8), suggest using `\Drupal::url()`, but this is [deprecated](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Aurl/8.2.x) in favour of [`Drupal\Core\Url`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x). I would like to avoid using deprecated methods as much as possible, but am stuck at trying to figure out what the `Drupal\Core\Url` equivalent is to `\Drupal::url('<front>')`. I am not sure which methods to be using, and nothing I've tried with `Url::fromUri()` has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Url::fromInternalUri](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromInternalUri/8.2.x) then instead of fromUri():

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromInternalUri/8.2.x

It specifically notes the use of `front` and `none`. But you can't pass the URL object or path tokens to RedirectResponse, as this is a Drupal construct. That class expects the following arguments:

http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.html

```
string  $url        The URL to redirect to
integer $status     The response status code
array   $headers    An array of response headers
```

`$url` needs to be a string, so on your URL object, call ->toString() to get the URL.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AtoString/8.2.x

Comment: I've tried Url::fromInternalUri(), but it's protected and can't be called from my function. I have also tried Url::fromUri('internal:/', array('absolute' => true))->toString() but this causes a browser crash from too many redirects. Url::fromUri('<front>')->toString() also does not work: "InvalidArgumentException: The URI '<front>' is invalid. You must use a valid URI scheme. in Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri() (line 280 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Url.php)."

Comment: Oh, wait a sec, the test function I was using had something strange going on in it. $response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse(Url::fromUri('internal:/', array('absolute' => true))->toString()); works.

Comment: @saramm1 $response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse(Url::fromU‌​ri('internal:/', array('absolute' => true))->toString()); this has got some mistakes in it, can you please check and write the correct one?